# Key "createdAt" for array with keys "0, 1" does not exist in note/show.html.twig at line 7

Tags: symfony, twig

I can show my `createdAt` field of all other tables, except this one in my `show` view. The code is

```
{% block body %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
            <small>Criado {{ notes.createdAt | date('d/m/Y') }}</small>
            {% if notes.updatedAt != notes.createdAt %}
                <small>Editado {{ notes.updatedAt | date('d/m/Y') }}</small>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
```

`showAction`

```
public function showAction($id)
{
    return $this->render('note/show.html.twig', array(
        'notes' => $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CDGBundle:Note')->findAllByBudget($id),
        'title' => 'Notas do cliente ' . $id
    ));
}
```

The `findAllByBudget` method was created inside of the repository:

```
public function findAllByBudget($id)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('n');

    return $qb
            ->orderBy('n.id', 'DESC')
            ->where(
                $qb->expr()->eq('n.budget', '?1')
            )
            ->setParameter(1, $id)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
}
```

Somehow I have problems on displaying from this specific entity only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an array of notes, so in twig template you have to use some loop to display each note. For example:

```
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
        {% for note in notes %}
            <small>Criado {{ note.createdAt | date('d/m/Y') }}</small>
            {% if note.updatedAt != note.createdAt %}
                <small>Editado {{ note.updatedAt | date('d/m/Y') }}</small>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```